# Content security policy in Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, content-security-policy

I had added the following content policy headers but if I check in the CSP evaluator it was showing **No Content Security Policy found.** I am using angular as frontend and Django rest framework.

```
Vary: Accept, Origin
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Security-Policy: font-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; default-src 'self'
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 476
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: Where exactly did you add this in Angular/Django? Please share the code that is supposed to add these CSPs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.